# Cannot access site on apache from machine on different Lan

Tags: web-server, local-area-network, apache-1.3

Hello I am new to apache and webservers and I need some help.

I wish to host website within a machine an browse to it from another machine in another enviornment as part of a test enviorn.

I am unable to browse to a website remotely. I have setup a website a lan, on a machine with an apache webserver (firewall is turned off on webserver machine).

- Apache is on machine B
- Machine B is on network Y

There is another laptop (A) on an adjacent network (network x).

I wish to browse to the website on other lan (Y) using A.

I can ping both ways, and can view website using "http://A.B.C.D/website.html" from within the webserver machine's browser.

Thanks

Comment: What connects both networks ? the network equipement may have a firewall.

Comment: Just a cisco 2811 router, there is no firewall. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1):

If you can ping from the laptop A to machine B, the IP is reachable from there. If you only can't reach port 80 (the webserver) on machine B from laptop A, (but it's available locally as you say) the only possible problems are that there is either a firewall in between that blocks accesses to port 80 or your apache is only listening on localhost and not on the external IP.

If it's a firewall, this can either be caused by a hardware or a software firewall (iptables/Windows firewall etc.).

To check if Apache is listening on the external interface or only on localhost. If it's only listening on localhost, use `netstat -tlnp` on machine B (if it's Linux). Change the Apache `Listen` directive to tell it on which IPs it should listen.

Comment: Note that The value you should set is either "0.0.0.0" if you want both loopback and remote access available, or set it to your eth0 address if you don't care for localhost access.